# Laravel: hasMany relationship breaks query with where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

This is my first Laravel project, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

I have `Clients` and `Campaigns` contollers, and clients are setup with `hasMany` campaigns

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function campaigns(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Campaign');

    }
}
```

in the Clients Show method, this query doesn't work:

```
$client = Client::find($id);
$campaigns = $client->campaigns
                 ->where(function($query) use($startdate, $enddate) {
                     $query->wherebetween('start_date', [$startdate, $enddate])
                           ->orwherebetween('end_date', [$startdate, $enddate]);
                 })
                 ->sortBy('start_date')
                 ->groupBy(function($val) {
                     return Carbon::parse($val->start_date)->format('F Y');
                 });
```

I get the error:
`explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`
The error page shows a red line on the `})` after the `orwhereBetween` clause.

But this query does work:

```
$campaigns = DB::table('campaigns')
                 ->where('client_id', $client->id)
                 ->where(function($query) use($startdate, $enddate) {
                     $query->wherebetween('start_date', [$startdate, $enddate])
                           ->orwherebetween('end_date', [$startdate, $enddate]);
                 })
                 ->orderBy('start_date')
                 ->get()
                 ->groupBy(function($val) {
                     return Carbon::parse($val->start_date)->format('F Y');
                 });
```

My problem is, the second query doens't let me access `$campaign->tasks` once I'm on the show view, which I need.

So, does anyone know why the where clause would cause an issue when accessing `$client->campaigns` but not when using `DB`?

Comment: could you please give us all the relevant code aswell as the actual error / exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because before you call **get** method the object is an instance of **Eloquent Builder** class and the **groupBy** method doesn't accepts any parameter as a closure. However after calling the get method it changes to an instance of **Collection** class which has **groupBy** method as well and it accepts closure.

By the way **sortBy** doen't belong to **Eloquent builder** instead you have to use **orderBy** before executing your query using **get** method.

Here are the available methods of Collection

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods

Try this code out and don't forget to call the methods camel case otherwise it can make you serious problems on deployment.

```
 $dates = $client->campaigns()
        ->where(function($query) use($startdate, $enddate) {
            $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$startdate, $enddate])
                ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$startdate, $enddate]);
        })
        ->orderBy('start_date')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->start_date)->format('F Y');
        });
        foreach($dates as $campaigns){
           foreach($campaigns as $campaign){
             dump($campaign->tasks);
           }
        }
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Can I ask though, is there a difference between doing `$client->campaigns()` and `$client->campaigns`? Also, when you mention camel casing, are you saying my method should be `public function Campaigns(){` in the controller? Thanks for the help, I've spent hours being confused by this one!

Comment: You're welcome my friend. No actually I meant whereBetween and orWhereBetween methods that should be written in camel case form.

Comment: When you call $clients->campaigns it executes the query and fetches the the data from database however $clients->campaigns() prepares your query to be executed until you call get method so you can chain it with other methods like where, whereHas etc.

Comment: To understand it clearly you can dd($client->campaigns) and dd($client->campaigns()->toSql()) and see the differences.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you, thanks for the explanation. I did `dd()` the `$dates` variable to see how it linked everything together, I'll take a look at that `toSql()` also to see the difference. Thanks for all the information! I'm finding the docs difficult to follow at the moment.